Issues Importing Demo Content in WordPress: "Failed to Import Media" Errors
I'm trying to import kalles demo content for my WordPress site using the One Click Demo Import plugin. However, after the files are downloaded, I encounter multiple [ERROR] Failed to import messages, specifically for media files.
Here's the error log:
---Downloaded files---
The import files for: Home Classic were successfully downloaded!
Initial max execution time = 360
Files info:
Site URL = https://lunomart.com
Data file = /home/u505807158/domains/lunomart.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/demo-content-import-file_2024-11-24__13-52-25.xml
Widget file = /home/u505807158/domains/lunomart.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2024/11/demo-widgets-import-file_2024-11-24__13-52-25.json
Customizer file = not defined!
Redux files:
not defined!

------
New AJAX call!
[ERROR] Failed to import "h2-bn1" (Media)
[ERROR] Failed to import "h2-bn2" (Media)
[ERROR] Failed to import "h2-bn3" (Media)
[ERROR] Failed to import "h2-bn4" (Media)
[ERROR] Failed to import "h2-bn6" (Media)
[ERROR] Failed to import "h4-bn5" (Media)
[ERROR] Failed to import "h5-bn4" (Media)
[ERROR] Failed to import "kalles@2x" (Media)
[ERROR] Failed to import "loobook" (Media)


I also see widget-related errors indicating that some widgets already exist, but my primary concern is the failed media imports. The full error log includes information about execution time and file paths:

Initial max execution time = 360
Site URL = xxxxxxxxxxx
Data file = /home/u505807158/domains/lunomart.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/...
Widget file = /home/u505807158/domains/lunomart.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/...

Steps I've already tried:
1-Increased PHP max_execution_time in php.ini to 360 and confirmed it is applied.
2-Checked file permissions for the wp-content/uploads folder.
3-Verified that the demo content files (XML and JSON) are present in the specified paths.
Despite these efforts, the media files are not being imported. Could this be related to file size, server settings, or some other issue?
My questions:
1-What could be causing the media import to fail?
2-Are there additional server settings or configurations I need to adjust (e.g.,
upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, etc.)?
3- How can I troubleshoot this issue further to successfully import all demo content?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

It would be resolve by that key points:

Increase PHP limits (memory_limit, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size) and check server logs.
Test manual media file import in WordPress Media Library.
Contact hosting support for configuration help and troubleshooting.

